# which port is being used by a local web server?

Tags: webserver, port, browserstack

We are using an internal server to host our staging website. I was trying to use [browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com/) to do compatibility testing on the virtual environment that they provide. In order to setup the virtual environment, I need to specify the **port** *which is being used by the local web server*. How can I find out which port is being used by our server? Do I need to go check the settings from the IIS in the server machine?

Comment: normally web server uses port 80, if you want to browse your site without specifying port in url

Comment: using port 80 worked! thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web server can run on any port. But the default port is 80. When you type in the URL of a web site the browser uses the default port 80 and connects to it. There are lot of occasions when other ports are used, mostly when more than one web server is needed in the same machine. Like webmin uses port 10000 by default.

For any web server not using port 80 you have to specify the port also with your url like `http://yoursite.com:port` in case of default webmin install it is like `http://localhost:10000`

Note:HTTP uses 80 and HTTPS uses 443 by default.

Answer (score 1):

This is documented in their tab for [local testing](http://www.browserstack.com/local-testing).

Basically you do not need to provide 80 as a port, because it will be used by default.

> If the port number is not provided, a default port number of 80 is
>   used. If the port number is present in the URL, it will be extracted
>   automatically. To test servers with SSL, check the HTTPS box. Once the
>   option is checked, you can enter a SSL port number that is independent
>   of the HTTP port number. When the connection is established, the HTTP
>   and HTTPS connections appear as separate links.